# RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message port has been closed for the process 87196

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin

I have a React 17 application where `react-scripts` was ejected to manually build Webpack config files. No rhyme or reason for that decision. At any rate, I cannot run on Node LTS because it generates the following error:

node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

> RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message
> port has been closed for the process 87196. ➜  frontend-user
> git:(issue_17) ✗
> modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/rpc/rpc-ipc/RpcIpcMessagePort.js:47:47
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {   code: undefined,
> signal: undefined }
>
> Node.js v18.18.2

It is suggesting that the issue is a dependency called `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`

```
✗ npm ls fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
futurewise-frontend@1.0.1 /Users/danielcortes/Projects/frontend-user
├── fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.2.13
└─┬ react-dev-utils@12.0.1 extraneous
  └── fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3 extraneous
```

Would upgrading to a newer version of this package resolve the error? What about just completely removing the package? It seems it just moves type checking to a separate process. Why would I need that? Typescript does type checking already.

Comment: We too faced the issue when we ejected our React app and added TS to it. We fixed it with the help of the issue reported [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/682).

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar, Thank you for sharing. The way I ended up resolving this was by upgrading all the Webpack config files.

Comment: "Why would I need that? Typescript does type checking already." TypeScript does that in both cases, this module just moves it out of the main process, so your project builds faster.